# Using Best_in_Place to edit attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, best-in-place

I am using the Best_in_Place gem to make areas on my site in place editable. I have two models: Student and Education, with the relationship being that each Student has_many Educations. I have the Best_in_place functionality working when editing attributes that are directly in the Student model, such as

```
<%=best_in_place @student, :name =>
```

However, I can't get it to update the attributes of an education.. with a line like

```
<%=best_in_place @education, :college =>
```

in the view of students/show, 
I get the error 
Started PUT "/educations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-25 13:06:57 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/educations")

and not only does it not work, the editable spot disappears completely. I can't figure out what's causing the problem, everything seems to be the same for both models/controllers. My routes are very simple:

```
resources :students
resources :educations
root :to => 'pages#home'
devise_for :students
```

as are my controllers:

```
def update
@student = Student.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @student.update_attributes(params[:student])
    format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

vs

```
def update
@education = Education.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
  if @education.update_attributes(params[:education])
    format.html { redirect_to @education, notice: 'Education was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @education.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

If I rake routes, I get:

```
educations GET    /educations(.:format)               educations#index
                          POST   /educations(.:format)               educations#create
            new_education GET    /educations/new(.:format)           educations#new
           edit_education GET    /educations/:id/edit(.:format)      educations#edit
                education GET    /educations/:id(.:format)           educations#show
                          PUT    /educations/:id(.:format)           educations#update
                          DELETE /educations/:id(.:format)           educations#destroy
students GET    /students(.:format)                 students#index
                          POST   /students(.:format)                 students#create
              new_student GET    /students/new(.:format)             students#new
             edit_student GET    /students/:id/edit(.:format)        students#edit
                  student GET    /students/:id(.:format)             students#show
                          PUT    /students/:id(.:format)             students#update
                          DELETE /students/:id(.:format)             students#destroy
```

Any pointers would be a huge help.

Comment: Did you find solution? I've got the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Things:

1. Your view syntax is off.  You're closing your tags with `=>` instead of `%>`.  So try this instead:

   `<%=best_in_place @student, :name %>`

   `<%=best_in_place @education, :college %>`
2. Try updating the `respond_to` blocks for `format.json` to `respond_with_bip(@student)`.  That should enable the user to edit via javascript, while leaving the user on the page to see their updates via AJAX.

[See ReadMe for best_in_place Controller response with respond_with_bip](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#controller-response-with-respond_with_bip)

See updates below:

```
def update
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @student.update_attributes(params[:student])
      format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { respond_with_bip(@student) }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end



def update
  @education = Education.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @education.update_attributes(params[:education])
      format.html { redirect_to @education, notice: 'Student was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { respond_with_bip(@education) }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @education.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```